# Why am i getting an intermittent water leak through my kitchen ceiling sometimes when people use the bath or shower above so not every time?

Tags: leaks

Why am I getting an intermittent leak through my kitchen ceiling when people use the bath or shower above? It isn't happening every time. It happened two weeks ago twice then didn't happen again till yesterday. Now it happened again today. My bath has a tiled side panel and I'm not sure how to get someone to look under the bath?

Comment: A minor drip type leak that builds up so it starts leaking into the kitchen.  Might also be caused by the way a person stands, they put weight on a specific spot that causes the leaking to happen.

Comment: I had an intermittent leak when the construction plumber did not connect the tub over flow.

Comment: Water might be leaking through if splashed out of the tub and allowed to pool on the floor or run down the walls. Perhaps it is intermittent because certain users are more careful with the shower curtain than others.

Comment: You need to bring this to the landlord's attention. I would not want somebody's bath/shower water dripping in my kitchen. I would consider this unsanitary and unsafe. I would expect the ceiling to fall ainwrunw  in the future.

Comment: Likely whether it leaks or not depends on where the person who is bathing stands.  Standing in the wrong place causes water to splash against some crack or seam.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your bathroom and specifics of the leak, I would check **bath drain seal** as this is easy to check and often the culprit.

Intermittent problems arise from how the tub or shower pan might flex depending on the weight and position of the person using it.

Seal age and tub movement may cause it to loosen, deteriorate and fail over time.

Inspect and replace the seal ring for the drain pipe under the tub, as well as the putty for the drain flange.

To remove the drain flange you can use pliers with a sufficiently long nose.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring this to the landlord's attention! I would not want somebody's bath/shower water dripping in my kitchen. I would consider this unsanitary and unsafe. I would not be surprised if the ceiling starts to fall in the future. You could also talk to your neighbor especially if they have kids. This could be the overing filling of a tub, sink or something else.